# Парсинг авито и каракули в классах

Tags: парсер

Подскажите пожалуйста, к человеко-читаемым классам идёт добавка, например class='price-text-**E1Y7h**' Они статичны или рандомно меняются? Если меняются, то где написано про логику этих изменений?

Comment: Так сами и посмотрите меняются они или нет. Напишите в чем у вас возникла сложность и как вы ее пробовали решить.

Comment: Я только учусь и у меня мало знаний, однако я попробовал перезагрузку компьютера и авторизоваться под вторым аккаунтов в авито. Всё работает, соответственно эта 'добавка' не изменилась. Если есть более продвинутые возможности для теста, подскажите. Вопрос задал, ибо в разрезе сегодняшнего дня хочу узнать, а не ждать продолжительного времени, пока эта 'добавка вдруг изменится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эта 'добавка' называется хэш,  делается через дополнительные модули, для того, чтобы при разработке проекта большой группой людей не было совпадений в классах. Предположительно они формируются во время деплоя и не меняются.

Comment: Сегодня проверил, эти части не меняются. Спасибо